Formulas for fitting points to a quadratic and log linear equation
I have a set of points $(x,y)$ in a coordinate plane. I understand that quadratic regression is the problem of fitting a parabola of the form:
$$ax^2 + bx + c$$
to those points. Assuming this link is correct, the formulas for $a, b$, and $c$ can be found via least squares regression:

$$\begin{align}
a &= \frac{\left(\sum (x^2-\overline{x^2})(y-\overline{y}) \sum (x-\overline{x})^2 \right) - \left(\sum (x-\overline{x})(y-\overline{y}) \sum (x-\overline{x})(x^2-\overline{x^2}) \right)}{\left(\sum (x-\overline{x})^2 \sum (x^2-\overline{x^2})^2 \right) - \left(\sum (x-\overline{x})(x^2-\overline{x^2}) \right)^2} \\ \\
b &= \frac{\left(\sum (x-\overline{x})(y-\overline{y}) \sum (x^2-\overline{x^2})^2 \right) - \left(\sum (x^2-\overline{x^2})(y-\overline{y}) \sum (x-\overline{x})(x^2-\overline{x^2}) \right)}{\left(\sum (x-\overline{x})^2 \sum (x^2-\overline{x^2})^2 \right) - \left(\sum (x-\overline{x})(x^2-\overline{x^2}) \right)^2} \\ \\
c &= \overline{y}-b\overline{x}-a\overline{x^2}
\end{align}$$

But what if I want to fit an equation of this form?

$$ax^2 + b(x \, \operatorname{lg}(x))+cx+d$$

This is similar to the above, but includes a log linear term. I know the $\log$ base will be $2$.
In this case, what would the formulas for $a, b, c$, and $d$ be?

If you look a little further down on the page $\sum xx$ is defined and is not what you think.
Normally if the independent variable is $x \lg x$ in one term it is in all the terms.  In that case you can define $x'=x \lg x$ and use the same formulas as you have been using.  If you don't want to do that you still have a linear fit because your model is linear in the parameters you are fitting-$a,b,c,d$.  You have a general linear least squares problem, which is treated in any numerical analysis text. There is a good discussion in section 14.3 of Numerical Recipes.

Ahh, thanks! Ok, I think I have updated my original question to have the correct formulas.
I don't want $x\lg x$ in every term. The reason I am doing this fit is to determine whether a given set of points fits better into $O(x^2)$, $O(x\lg x)$, $O(x)$, or $O(1)$.

Then you have no need to rescale $x$.  The book I referenced says you can have a fit of the form $af(x)+bg(x)+ch(x)$ with perhaps more terms where $f,g,h$ can be wildly nonlinear functions of $x$ and gives programs to solve the problem.  If you have data over a large enough range in $x$ it should be quite obvious what the dominant term is.  Just divide your data by each function and see which approaches a constant.
